# Pascal Battleships Loadgame

Tags: pascal, lazarus

The following code uses a game saved in a text file in the form 0/8B1/8B1/8B1/1P6B1/1P8/7S2/7S2/1AAAAA1S2/5DDD2

(for example) and puts the correct pieces in a board. The numbers represent a series of consecutive spaces and / means a new row. The letters represent the ship in that cell of the board ( a two dimensional array).

When I run it it come sup with EXTERNAL SIGSEGV and shows me assembly code saying 00403D61 833a00                   cmpl   $0x0,(%edx)

Does anyone know what is wrong with it and how to fix it?

```
Procedure LoadGame(FileName : String; Var Board : TBoard);
Var
  Line : String;
  CurrentFile : Text;
  Row , count : Integer;
  column, counter: Integer;
Begin
  AssignFile(CurrentFile, FileName);
  Reset(CurrentFile);
  Readln(CurrentFile, Line);
  for counter := 1 to length(line) do
  begin
    if (Line[counter] in ['A'..'Z','m','h']) then
    begin
      board[row,column]:=line[counter];
      column:=column+1;
    end
    else
      if line[counter]='0' then
      begin
        for column := 0 to 9 do
        begin
          board[row,column]:='-';
        end;
      end
      else
        If line[counter]='/' then
        begin
          row :=row+1;
          column:=0;
        end
        else 
          for count := 0 to (strtoint(line[counter])-1) do
          begin
            Board[row,column+count] :='-';
            column:=column+1;
          end;
  end;
  CloseFile(CurrentFile);
End;
```

Comment: You should be more accurate with  `row` and `column` variables which changes in chaotic ways (for the first glance) inside the main loop.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended as a substitute for debugging

Comment: But there are other forums that can help with debugging, on StackExchange. I am not 100% sure, but I guess http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialised the variables `row` and `column` before you use them.  You must do that, because since they are local variables (on the stack), they will contain random values when LoadGame is called.  See changes/suggestions below.  I haven't debugged your code, that's for you to do.

```
Procedure LoadGame(FileName : String; Var Board : TBoard);
Var
  Line : String;
  CurrentFile : Text;
  Row , count : Integer;
  column, counter: Integer;
Begin
  // Ideally, you should initialise each cell of the board with some value not used in the following so you can easily verify the effect of the loading operation

  AssignFile(CurrentFile, FileName);
  Reset(CurrentFile);
  Readln(CurrentFile, Line);

  // initialise Row and Column
  Row := 0;     // assuming the cells are zero-based
  Column := 0;  // ditto

  for counter := 1 to length(line) do
    begin
      if (Line[counter] in ['A'..'Z','m','h']) then
      begin
        board[row,column]:=line[counter];
        column:=column+1;
      end
      else
      if line[counter]='0' then
      begin
        for column := 0 to 9 do
          begin
            board[row,column]:='-';
          end;
      end
      else If line[counter]='/' then
      begin
        row :=row+1;
        column:=0;
      end

      else for count := 0 to (strtoint(line[counter])-1) do
      begin
        Board[row,column+count] :='-';
        column:=column+1;
      end;
  end;

  CloseFile(CurrentFile);
End;
```